# InstallData.php not executing on Magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento2.2, installdata

I have the following InstallData.php in my Setup directory in my module. The script does not seem to execute at all. I have tried throwing an Exception at the beginning, dumping and dying, etc. Nothing seems to stop the script or output and information while running setup:upgrade.

NB: I have removed the module's row from the setup_module table before each run. I've also tried with EavSetupFactory - no luck there either.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
<?php

namespace Tridum\Thumbnail\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    /**
     *
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Category::ENTITY,
            'thumbnail',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Category Thumbnail',
                'input' => 'image',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 9,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'default' => null,
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
<?php
namespace Tridum\Thumbnail\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;


    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;  
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'thumbnail',
            [
                 'group'        => 'General Information',
                 'label'        => 'Category Thumbnail',
                 'type'         => 'varchar',
                 'input'        => 'image',
                 'required'     => false,
                 'sort_order'   => 9,
                 'backend'      => '\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                 'global'       => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. I pasted in your code, deleted the row for the module from the setup_module table, and then ran "magento setup:upgrade". Still no thumbnail eav_attribute. I must be missing something else?

Comment: Can you please check that you are put proper code and run command, because I already used same code to create attibute and it working fine.

Comment: Yes, the code is exact. Are there other steps I am missing? Is there a good way to debug these install scripts? There is no output anywhere saying whether these scripts are running or not. If I throw an Exception on the first line of the install method, I never see the Exception.

Comment: You can cross verify the code from magento root. You can try to run the script from there, so you get idea script is working.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "magento root" or "run the script from there." Where is there? Are you saying move InstallData.php to /pub and access the script from the browser?

Comment: No, Magento root means the place where main index.php is avilable.